# Bash script - Check if a file exists

Tags: bash, file, if-statement, conditional-statements

I need to check if a file with a specific extension exists and if it is not empty.
The problem is that I don't know the name of the file, just the extension and the path.

Here my solution with an known name

```
FILE="/Users/test/my.out"
if [[ -f $FILE  &&  -s $FILE ]] ; then echo "EXIST"; fi
```

Using

```
FILE="/Users/test/*.out"
```

Do not work

Comment: What if you have multiple files that match that pattern? Try `FILE=$(ls /Users/test/*.out)`

Comment: The initial condition is that in this folder will be just one file .out

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try

```
FILE=$(ls "Downloads/*.zip" 2>/dev/null)
```

Only works, if there is only a single file.

Comment: This works, thanks! If I put in a while loop this check, if the file does not exist yet, an output "ls: /Users/test/*.out: No such file or directory" is displayed. Is there any way to avoid this output?

Comment: See my edit, the 2>/dev/null suppresses the error. By the way, I guess this is a very bad hackjob...

Comment: Thanks everyone for downvoting and telling the world your reasons. Some arguments against it can be found [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)..

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you use an array, in case there are multiple files:

```
arr=( /Users/test/*.out )

if (( ${#arr[@]} > 0 )) && [[ -s "${arr[0]}" ]]
then
    ...
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either use @dogbane's solution using an array or use a loop:

```
dir=/users/test
for file in "${dir}"/*.out; do
    break
done

if [ -f "${file}" ] && [ -s "${file}" ]; then
    echo "found a regular, non-empty .out file: ${file}"
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this should do:

```
if [ -f ${var} ]; then
   if [ -s ${var} ]; then
      echo  "Found $var"
   fi
fi
```